# K-competitive online/offline algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Given a sequence A = [a1, a2, ··· , an] of n distinct elements, where 1 ≤ ai ≤ k for i = 1, 2, ··· , n.
Consider the following on-line algorithm Algo for finding the maximum element of A.

```
Algo(A, k):
    for i = 1 to n:
      if ai ≥ √k:
        return ai
    return 1
```

Prove that Algo is 1/√k -competitive

Im not sure how to solve this. But i thought i should show that Algo <= (Optimal Offline algo)/√k

The optimal offline algo takes O(n) to determine the maximum element of A.

If there is 4 elements [1,2,3,100], then the online algo has to examine all of the elements and the runtime here should also be O(n).

Therefore this "Algo <= (Optimal Offline algo)/√k" should not be correct?

Comment: Approximation/competitive ratios are about quality (for this problem, the ratio of the true maximum to the returned element) and not running time.

Comment: What does for instances 1/2-competitive and 2-competitive says about the quality? I thought that 1 is optimal and 2 is worse, then 1/2 should be better than optimal?

Comment: The terminology is a bit messy. Some folks think that 2-approximation should be reserved for a minimization problem and 1/2-approximation for a maximization problem; others say 2-approximation for both.

Comment: I think i got it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When i read the definition im getting confused. "An online algorithm A is c-competitive if for all input I, the total cost of A on I is C_A(I) >= C_OPT(I)/c + b where C_OPT(I) is the total cost of some offline algorithm OPT on input I". If the input would be [2,3,4] Then the total cost is 1 for A and 3 for C_OPT, then this seems to not be correct "C_A(I) >= C_OPT(I)/c + b". Should i just change the C_A and C_OPT to the values? Ex. C_A = 2, C_OPT = 4 and c = √4

Comment: The definition seems wrong. Ignoring b (because I don't want to get into the weeds of how the quantification works), for a maximization problem, the algorithm should be c-competitive if for all inputs I, we have C_A(I) ≥ c C_OPT(I). For I = [2, 3, 4] and k = 4 and c = 1/√k, we have C_A(I) = 2 and C_OPT(I) = 4, and C_A(I) = 2 ≥ 2 = (1/√k) 4 = c C_OPT(I).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe you already answered this question but when should i use the value for the input and when should i use the cost of the algorithm? I have an example in my slides about to find the shortest path, for that problem the offline solution costs 9 units and the online solution is 9*Offline solution hence the algorithm is 9-competitive. But in this case it does not work to use the Actual cost

Comment: With online algorithms the running time of the algorithm is generally of secondary concern to the quality, since the online-ness of the algorithm tends to be more constraining than running time.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the good explanations!